# GAE Blob Store get file size

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blobstore, google-cloud-storage

I try to get the size of a file stored in Google Cloud Storage from Google App Engine in Java,

I tried this :

```
FileService fileService = FileServiceFactory.getFileService();
AppEngineFile appEngineFile = fileService.getBlobFile(new BlobKey("blob key"));
int size = (int) fileService.stat(appEngineFile).getLength().longValue();
```

But it is returning 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the [`BlobInfo.getSize()`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/blobstore/BlobInfo#getSize%28%29):

```
BlobInfoFactory blobInfoFactory = new BlobInfoFactory();
BlobInfo blobInfo = blobInfoFactory.loadBlobInfo(new BlobKey("blob key"))
Long blobSize = blobInfo.getSize();
```